# An interface class in java is a blueprint to do things

Tags: java, methods, interface, abstract, implementation

If there is no implementation body in the interface class, then how can it put a function? I know it is implemented by other classes but the methods in an interface exist for what they can achieve so they have some skills already. Then they should have some codes in them. Then why do they have empty bodies?

Comment: an interface says that an object shall be able to do some thing, without defining *how* it shall do that - that's up to the class that implements the interface.

Comment: The **declaration** of methods of an interface are not **implementations** and you cannot call them directly for the simple reason that you cannot even **instantiate** the interface itself (it doesn't have a constructor). A method declaration doesn't contain any runnable code.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Interfaces are not reducing code repetition. It is more about **enforcing a good design**.  Thats why we are using interfaces when we are coding.
And also interface sole purpose is to be implemented by one or more classes.

Comment: I feel like interfaces are just a guide to organizing your code()blueprint or design concept). Just organize your code, and do whatever you want to do inside your code. When it is implemented by a class this is very true because you have to inherit all the properties, but when you create an object (Webdriver instances for example) your object can use the methods in it when it is necessary. Please let me know if you agree.  with me.